# Start embed jetty in java code, how to make it auto reload *.jsp/*.css/*.js?

Tags: java, jetty, reload

In my project, we start jetty server in java code, like:

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Server server= new Server();
    server.setThreadPool(createThreadPool());
    server.addConnector(createConnector());
    server.setHandler(new WebAppContext(getWarRootPath(), "/"));
    server.setStopAtShutdown(true);
    server.start();
}
```

It works well, but the only problem is that if we modify *.jsp or *.js or *.css when jetty is running, we can't see the changes by refreshing the brower. I have to restart the program.

Is there any way to make it auto reload? (I must start jetty in java code, so no 3rd-putty plugins can be used here)

Answer (score 2):

Your simple use of WebAppContext means that your webapp content is being expanded / copied / moved / managed in the various servlet temp directories.  Your project's `*.jsp` and `*.js` and `*.css` are not live.

The way other tooling (like `jetty-maven-plugin`) accomplishes this is to restart the webapp when a file change is detected.

Example (pseudo-code):

```java
String webroot = getWarRootPath();
WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext(webroot, "/");
server.setHandler(webapp);

scanner.setMonitorDirectory(webroot);
scanner.addListener(this);

...

public void onScannerEvent(ScannerEvent evt) {
    if(!evt.path.isFile()) {
        return; // no point restarting on directory only event
    }
    webapp.stop();
    if(evt.isNew() || evt.wasDeleted()) {
        reconfigureScanner();
    }
    webapp.start();
}
```

If you have Java 7 in use, you can look into its `java.nio.file.Watch*` facilities for this, or you can use the `org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner` (legacy code) to accomplish the [same end goal](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.1.0.v20131115/jetty-maven-plugin/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/maven/plugin/JettyRunMojo.java#L478-L492).

Comment: Out of interest Joakim, would it possible to use a combination of WebAppProvider and DeploymentManager similar to your answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/14368310/129822. Setting setMonitoredDirName and setScanInterval.

Comment: @Andrew certainly can, that's how the Jetty distribution itself operates.